# Unresolved external symbol error while trying to run PARDISO on windows 10

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, fortran, unresolved-external, pardiso

I downloaded the PARDISO libraries from https://www.pardiso-project.org and obtained the license too. As per the user manual, I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 as well as Intel Parallel XE 2020 for the cl and Intel compilers. I have placed the .dll file, the .lib file and the .exp file along with the license (.lic file) in c:\users\hp. Microsoft Visual Studio has been installed and the source and repository folders are placed in c:\users\hp\Source.

I tried to run the sample code on Visual Studio : https://pardiso-project.org/manual/pardiso_unsym.f (equivalent C++ code is https://pardiso-project.org/manual/pardiso_unsym.cpp)

I got the following errors:

For the C++ code:

> unresolved external symbol pardisoinit referenced in function main Trial4 C:\Users\hp\source\repos\Trial4\Trial4\tryout1.obj   1

For the Fortran code:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PARDISOINIT referenced in function _MAIN__      Tryout2.obj

I know that all this has something to do with the libraries being placed in the correct place but I am unable to figure it out correctly. Could someone tell me how I can solve this problem? I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: It's not a matter of putting the libraries in the correct place, that only applies to the DLL (and maybe the license file). This issue is that you  have to tell Visual Studio to link with the library, and you have to tell Visual Studio where you put the library. The library itself can go anywhere, just tell Visual Studio about it.

Comment: @john Could you tell me how to do this? I am guessing that I need to go along : Project --> Property Pages --> Linker --> *and then what?????*

Comment: Project->Linker->Input->Additional Dependences, this is where you put the name of the library (don't forget the .lib extension), Project->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories, this is where you put the location of the library. Your project is likely to have several 'platforms' and 'configurations`. Make sure that you are building the correct one, and changing the settings for the correct one.

Comment: it is not a free library, can't test

Comment: @Landstalker You just need to sign up. It isn't a paid one.

Comment: @john It works. Thanks a lot. You can just put the same in an answer if you wish. I will mark it correct.